# Converting XML to HTML

Tags: html, xml, cocoa-touch, ios

I have made a 'RSS Feed' app through parsing XML. Now I want to load the content into a `UIWebView` within a detail view, but not as a generic browser. I know that HTML content can be loaded in a `UIWebView`, so I want to convert the XML feed's content to HTML content and load it in the web view.

How could this be done?

Answer (score 1):

Generally, you can convert XML to XHTML using XSLT.

Unfortunately, as the following SO questions show, using the existing libxslt (and having a solution fully on the client) is not allowed on iOS for some reason. Or at least, has not been allowed in the past -- no idea if this is still true for iOS 4.3+.

[Version of XSLT in iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/462440/version-of-xslt-in-iphone)

[Alternative to NSXMLDocument on the iPhone for XSLT purposes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/712658/alternative-to-nsxmldocument-on-the-iphone-for-xslt-purposes)

[How do I include libxslt in my iPhone app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3640901/how-do-i-include-libxslt-in-my-iphone-app)

[No XSLTProcessor() support in Safari?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1705584/no-xsltprocessor-support-in-safari)

You may need to implement a server-side solution. (Which might not necessarily be a bad thing, since doing the work server-side means faster clients)

Comment: Another possibility is the recently released Saxon-CE javascript implementation of the Saxon XSLT engine http://www.saxonica.com/ce/download.xml. I've used some of the sites that are implemented with it on iOS Safari and they seem to work acceptably.

Answer (score 1):

The RSS should have a "link" tag for every feed, which (link) holds the URL of the specific news tag. You can just load the link on a uiWebView.